# Translating Ionic video fileURI to dataURL, for Firebase upload

Tags: firebase, ionic3, file-uri

I have a fileURI that i am trying to convert into a dataURL so that I can upload it to Firebase.

Currently I get the path of `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/69BCC8B8-D539-4BA3-AD6B-B3ECBD8DEDE9/Library/Caches/myvideo_17.mp4`, but I need this to be converted into a way (BLOB, String, etc...) so that I can upload the video to Firebase.

I have been messing around with the Cordova File plugin, but i cannot seem to input the correct information to get it to output the file dataUrl...

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after taking a few weeks off, and coming back to this, I figured out the issue.

Turns out that the plugin I have been using was stripping the fileURI (which I have not previously used), of the **VERY** important `file://` part of the string. So I was left with `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/69BCC8B8-D539-4BA3-AD6B-B3ECBD8DEDE9/Library/Caches/myvideo_17.mp4`.

So after fixing the string (like you do when using base64Url's). I ended up with the following:

`'file://' + fileURI`;

Which all together, my code now looks like this:

```
resolveFileSystemUrl(media){
 let fixed = 'file://' + media;
 this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(fixed)
 .then(result => {
   this.resolveFileEntry(result);
 }).catch(err => {console.error('Error resolving the file system url'); });
}


resolveFileEntry(res) {
 res.file((resFile) => {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(resFile);
  reader.onloadend = (evt: any) => {
    // the base64 of the video is: evt.target.result
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: What are you importing for `this.file` ?

Comment: @Grant I asked this like 4 years ago lol, but I think that it was `cordova-plugin-file`, though I have no idea if this answer still holds up in the latest ionic / cordova versions.